# Downloading complete maven remote repository to Local repository?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

Is there any to get the entire remote repository, say from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ , to my local repository (to `%USERPROFILE%`)?

Comment: I thought this is done every time you start maven!? Along with the rest of the internet

Comment: It's hard to imagine why you'd want to do this.

Comment: I once worked with some pretty great programmers in Nepal, who, when the power went out, ran their computers off of car batteries. If you don't have a consistent net connection, Maven can be kind of a pain. That said, you shouldn't have to wget the entire repository.

Comment: @johnstok It's easy to imagine if you want to setup a repo for all you guys who stay in a intranet without internet access. ;-) BTW proxy is not allowed there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From http://maven.apache.org/community.html:

> ### Being a Good Maven Citizen
>
> The concept of a public repository
>   built into the core architecture of
>   Maven makes it necessarily
>   community-centric. There are a few
>   simple things that Maven users may do
>   to help keep that community thriving.
>
> #### Be a Kind Public Repository User
>
> The best thing that a user can do is
>   to set up their own remote repository
>   mirror containing the projects needed.
>   There are several tools to make this
>   simpler, such as [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or [Archiva](http://maven.apache.org/archiva/).
>   This reduces strain on the Maven
>   central repository, and allows new
>   users to get acquainted with Maven
>   easier and quicker. This is especially
>   important for power-users and
>   corporations. The incentive behind
>   this is, controlling your own servers
>   can give you desired level of security
>   and more control over uptime,
>   resulting in a better experience for
>   your users. With that said, keep the
>   following sentiment in mind:
>
> *DO NOT wget THE ENTIRE REPOSITORY!*
>
> Please take only the jars you need. We
>   understand this is may entail more
>   work, but grabbing all 9+ Gigs of
>   binaries really kills our servers.
>
> #### Host a Mirror
>
> As an extention to the previous
>   statement, if you have access to a
>   large data repository with lots of
>   bandwidth, please consider becomming a
>   mirror for the Maven central
>   repository.
>
> As you can imagine, thousands of users
>   downloading can put quite a strain on
>   one server. If you wish to be a
>   mirror, please file a request in the
>   [Maven Project Administration](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPA) JIRA
>   project.
>
> #### Host a Public Repository
>
> If you have any projects that you wish
>   others to use, host them on your own
>   public repository. That way, your
>   users can simply add your repository
>   to their own project repo list, and
>   viola! Maven can keep you and your
>   users in synch, growing your user-base
>   due simply to its new-found ease of
>   use.

Maybe if you explain why you'd like to get the whole central repo in `%USERPROFILE%` I could provide a better answer (if you you need to go offline, there are smarter solutions than getting 9+ gigs of artifacts). But for now, I don't get the point.

Comment: Hello thaks for your reply , After downloading the entire repository to my local %USERPROFILE% , i must upload the entire content(jars..) to the internal-repository.. and i need to distribute that internal repository ..  Yes it must be an offiline job once the internal repository is set

Comment: @srinannapa Don't crawl the entire repository, use what you need only, use a proxying enterprise repository. If you need to distribute 9+ Gigs of binaries, there **must be** something wrong with your approach...

Comment: Don't you think when you need to set up a repository for the first time in an corporate where you need to work offline ???? Do you have any other approach.

Comment: @srinannapa You won't convince me that you'll need the entire repository. And if you think you do, still, don't crawl the entire repository. Contact the maven guys and see how to setup a mirror. Everything is written black on white above. BTW, if you need to google something, are you going to crawl the entire web?!?

Comment: Some times it is useful if you save the the web pages for quick ref., and when i'm not online that won't stop my work.  
What do you feel about rsync ?? but no idea who allows this rsync repo1.mavem.com?? or any other mirror?

Comment: @srinannapa Get in touch with the Maven PMC and discuss this with them. I've added a link to their Jira. Also have a look at http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/12/maintain-an-essential-public-resource-the-central-maven-repository/.

Comment: @PascalThivent
would it be possible to have the entire repository on torrent though? , ive seen linux distros being distributed via torrent too, or is it out there already?  . I'd be more than willing to seed if there is already as I have unlimited fiber internet anyway at home  I only wanted to get the entire repository as the internet at work is super slow. Haix.

Comment: My reason is automation. 2 use cases. 
(1) get all hash-files (X-Y.pom.sha1) so that I can make a mapping of "hash to artifact". I need that to implement cve-scanning, finding jar on filesystem -> mapping to artifact -> finding reported cve:s on that artifact.
(2) Construct  a mapping of dependents (opposite to dependencies) of an artifact, answeing the question "who is using artifact X".

Answer (score 15):

I just had to mirror a private product repo to make available on another machine. lftp worked just fine:

```
$ lftp http://my.repo.example.com/product/maven
mirror --no-empty-dirs --parallel=3 . my-local-repo
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail how have you performed this

Comment: @srinannapa: I have added formatting to make solution readable. Is everything clear now? It is just a lftp command in unix shell and then a command within the lftp command line user interface.

Comment: This in fact answers the question's functionality. Accepted answer should not be ignored. lftp worked for me on ubuntu 16.04 no problemo when I needed to host a maven repo in s3.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you would do that using Maven. It might be useful to explain what you are trying to achieve - at a guess you want a local cache?

What you might be looking for really is a local repository manager like Sonatype's [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/). These repository managers provide a local cache for remote repositories, as well as providing somewhere for you to put your code.

Comment: Yes but all the time i need to be online.. That's the part i want to avoid , the works goes offline

Comment: @srinannapa If you want to prepare yourself for offline work consider using the [dependency:go-offline](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) plugin/gaol. This off course only gets the dependencies of an existing project.

Answer (score -3):

"wget -m http://site.to.mirror.com"  should do it

-m stands for "mirror".